# Slicing from nth to nth element but considering the last index where it left of

Tags: python

**QUESTION:** Is there any smart way to use step parameter or any other approach that would slice from the last sliced grouping element, where it left of?

**Concretely:** e[1:10], e[11:19], e[19:28]...etc (from breaking variable (till the first 10th element, from upcoming 9th element, next 9th, next 8th, next 8th, next 8th, next 8th) ?

stored list of every slicing that should happen inside img_list main variable 10th element from there the 9th element, from there 9th etc...

```
breaking
Out[386]: [10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8]
```

list tuple, as the main variable to manipulate with:

```
img_list = list([(147.83999633789062, 277.20001220703125, 30, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 309.7200012207031, 50, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 331.44000244140625, 66, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 359.6400146484375, 94, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 374.4000244140625, 106, 0),
 (148.07998657226562, 388.20001220703125, 114, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 404.1600036621094, 130, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 420.1200256347656, 146, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 445.9200134277344, 166, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 471.7200012207031, 182, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 279.1200256347656, 34, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 300.2400207519531, 34, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 321.3600158691406, 58, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 350.6400146484375, 82, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 380.0400085449219, 110, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 402.2400207519531, 110, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 424.5600280761719, 150, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 455.0400085449219, 178, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 480.84002685546875, 198, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 276.84002685546875, 26, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 297.96002197265625, 26, 0),
 (250.32000732421875, 318.96002197265625, 54, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 351.84002685546875, 86, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 375.2400207519531, 86, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 398.760009765625, 126, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 428.2799987792969, 154, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 451.8000183105469, 154, 0),
 (250.32000732421875, 474.96002197265625, 190, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 277.08001708984375, 22, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 297.96002197265625, 38, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 326.0400085449219, 62, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 352.32000732421875, 90, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 380.4000244140625, 90, 0),
 (306.6000061035156, 408.96002197265625, 134, 0),
 (306.6000061035156, 432.0, 134, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 454.6800231933594, 174, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 482.760009765625, 202, 0),
 (363.7200012207031, 277.08001708984375, 18, 0),
 (363.8399963378906, 304.9200134277344, 46, 0),
```

looping through each tuple (and it's index)

```
for indx, e in enumerate(img_list, start =1):
    print(indx,e)
1 (147.83999633789062, 277.20001220703125, 30, 0)
2 (147.95999145507812, 309.7200012207031, 50, 0)
3 (147.95999145507812, 331.44000244140625, 66, 0)
4 (147.95999145507812, 359.6400146484375, 94, 0)
5 (147.95999145507812, 374.4000244140625, 106, 0)
6 (148.07998657226562, 388.20001220703125, 114, 0)
7 (147.95999145507812, 404.1600036621094, 130, 0)
8 (147.95999145507812, 420.1200256347656, 146, 0)
9 (147.95999145507812, 445.9200134277344, 166, 0)
10 (147.95999145507812, 471.7200012207031, 182, 0)
11 (199.07998657226562, 279.1200256347656, 34, 0)
12 (199.07998657226562, 300.2400207519531, 34, 0)
13 (199.07998657226562, 321.3600158691406, 58, 0)
14 (199.07998657226562, 350.6400146484375, 82, 0)
15 (199.07998657226562, 380.0400085449219, 110, 0)
16 (199.07998657226562, 402.2400207519531, 110, 0)
17 (199.07998657226562, 424.5600280761719, 150, 0)
18 (199.07998657226562, 455.0400085449219, 178, 0)
19 (199.07998657226562, 480.84002685546875, 198, 0)
20 (250.20001220703125, 276.84002685546875, 26, 0)
21 (250.20001220703125, 297.96002197265625, 26, 0)
22 (250.32000732421875, 318.96002197265625, 54, 0)
23 (250.20001220703125, 351.84002685546875, 86, 0)
24 (250.20001220703125, 375.2400207519531, 86, 0)
25 (250.20001220703125, 398.760009765625, 126, 0)
26 (250.20001220703125, 428.2799987792969, 154, 0)
27 (250.20001220703125, 451.8000183105469, 154, 0)
28 (250.32000732421875, 474.96002197265625, 190, 0)
29 (306.9599914550781, 277.08001708984375, 22, 0)
30 (306.9599914550781, 297.96002197265625, 38, 0)
31 (306.9599914550781, 326.0400085449219, 62, 0)
32 (306.9599914550781, 352.32000732421875, 90, 0)
33 (306.9599914550781, 380.4000244140625, 90, 0)
34 (306.6000061035156, 408.96002197265625, 134, 0)
35 (306.6000061035156, 432.0, 134, 0)
36 (306.9599914550781, 454.6800231933594, 174, 0)
37 (306.9599914550781, 482.760009765625, 202, 0)
38 (363.7200012207031, 277.08001708984375, 18, 0)
39 (363.8399963378906, 304.9200134277344, 46, 0)
40 (363.8399963378906, 333.1200256347656, 78, 0)
41 (363.8399963378906, 363.6000061035156, 90, 0)
42 (363.8399963378906, 391.6800231933594, 122, 0)
43 (363.8399963378906, 417.2400207519531, 142, 0)
44 (363.8399963378906, 443.0400085449219, 158, 0)
```

Comment: Why not just use a loop and maintain a variable that tracks the next starting point in `img_list` for the next group, ie: `i = 1; img_list[i:i+10];i += 10; img_list[i:i+9];i += 9;...` ? - seems, btw, that `i` should start at `0`, not `1`, but I'm going by your proposed "Concrete result".

Comment: @Steve  I thought about the same I did try this approach. however, with the e[i:i+10] we're just accessing the tuples element and not the grouping tuples as a whole. That's where it all gets kinda messed up. My bad for formulating the question a bit confusingly I geuss.

Comment: But "grouping" is a separate issue, regardless of how you arrive at the specific slices.  You see only to be asking here about how to come up with each of the slices.

Comment: @Steve I see your point. Still with the aforementioned solutions there is no specific condition that would control when to add the 10th,9th, 9th... etc element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a step parameter because the "step" changes for each iteration.  I see no reason to not therefore use a simple loop where you can apply the appropriate step to a tracked position in each iteration.
Here's a concrete illustration of what I suggest in the comments:

```
img_list = list([(147.83999633789062, 277.20001220703125, 30, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 309.7200012207031, 50, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 331.44000244140625, 66, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 359.6400146484375, 94, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 374.4000244140625, 106, 0),
 (148.07998657226562, 388.20001220703125, 114, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 404.1600036621094, 130, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 420.1200256347656, 146, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 445.9200134277344, 166, 0),
 (147.95999145507812, 471.7200012207031, 182, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 279.1200256347656, 34, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 300.2400207519531, 34, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 321.3600158691406, 58, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 350.6400146484375, 82, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 380.0400085449219, 110, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 402.2400207519531, 110, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 424.5600280761719, 150, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 455.0400085449219, 178, 0),
 (199.07998657226562, 480.84002685546875, 198, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 276.84002685546875, 26, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 297.96002197265625, 26, 0),
 (250.32000732421875, 318.96002197265625, 54, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 351.84002685546875, 86, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 375.2400207519531, 86, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 398.760009765625, 126, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 428.2799987792969, 154, 0),
 (250.20001220703125, 451.8000183105469, 154, 0),
 (250.32000732421875, 474.96002197265625, 190, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 277.08001708984375, 22, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 297.96002197265625, 38, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 326.0400085449219, 62, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 352.32000732421875, 90, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 380.4000244140625, 90, 0),
 (306.6000061035156, 408.96002197265625, 134, 0),
 (306.6000061035156, 432.0, 134, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 454.6800231933594, 174, 0),
 (306.9599914550781, 482.760009765625, 202, 0),
 (363.7200012207031, 277.08001708984375, 18, 0),
 (363.8399963378906, 304.9200134277344, 46, 0)])

group_counts = [10, 9, 9] # etc., etc. ...

p = 0
for i, c in enumerate(group_counts):
    group = img_list[p:p+c]
    print("{}:{} #{} - {}".format(p, p+c, i+1, group))
    # Do whatever you want with each slice (via "group") here
    p += c
```

Result:

```
0:10 #1 - [(147.83999633789062, 277.20001220703125, 30, 0), (147.95999145507812, 309.7200012207031, 50, 0), (147.95999145507812, 331.44000244140625, 66, 0), (147.95999145507812, 359.6400146484375, 94, 0), (147.95999145507812, 374.4000244140625, 106, 0), (148.07998657226562, 388.20001220703125, 114, 0), (147.95999145507812, 404.1600036621094, 130, 0), (147.95999145507812, 420.1200256347656, 146, 0), (147.95999145507812, 445.9200134277344, 166, 0), (147.95999145507812, 471.7200012207031, 182, 0)]
10:19 #2 - [(199.07998657226562, 279.1200256347656, 34, 0), (199.07998657226562, 300.2400207519531, 34, 0), (199.07998657226562, 321.3600158691406, 58, 0), (199.07998657226562, 350.6400146484375, 82, 0), (199.07998657226562, 380.0400085449219, 110, 0), (199.07998657226562, 402.2400207519531, 110, 0), (199.07998657226562, 424.5600280761719, 150, 0), (199.07998657226562, 455.0400085449219, 178, 0), (199.07998657226562, 480.84002685546875, 198, 0)]
19:28 #3 - [(250.20001220703125, 276.84002685546875, 26, 0), (250.20001220703125, 297.96002197265625, 26, 0), (250.32000732421875, 318.96002197265625, 54, 0), (250.20001220703125, 351.84002685546875, 86, 0), (250.20001220703125, 375.2400207519531, 86, 0), (250.20001220703125, 398.760009765625, 126, 0), (250.20001220703125, 428.2799987792969, 154, 0), (250.20001220703125, 451.8000183105469, 154, 0), (250.32000732421875, 474.96002197265625, 190, 0)]
...
```

Again, what you do with each slice is another matter.  Your question here seems to be just one of how to come up with each slice.

Comment: the idea is to have a condition so that I know exactly when the new "group" has started and ultimately store it in a dictionary. From this illustration I'm still missing to track down when did the next "group" start from (1:10 1st, 10:19 2nd etc etc)

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying is the problem.  In my example, `i` designates the start of the next group for each iteration....`[i:i+c]` == `1:10`, `10:19`, etc. etc.  If you need `1st`, `2nd`, etc., you can add the use of `enumerate` to get `0, 1, 2...` for each time through the loop. This would give you exactly what you describe in the above comment.